# Webserver stop working after script with selenium

Tags: python, php, apache, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a script in `Python`, which opens some website using `Selenium`, makes some actions and closes the site. If I launch by myself it works, but if I try to launch it using a `php` file then it works but after completion, the script webserver doesn't ask. I just can fix it by restarting `Apache`. Does anyone knows where is the problem?

php file

```
<?php
    $result = shell_exec('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\find.py');
    
    echo "<div class='area'>";
    echo $result;
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

python script

```
import sys
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import unittest
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://smolensklib.ru/scripts_cut/zgate.exe?Init+souball.xml,simple.xsl+rus")

author = driver.find_element_by_name("TERM_1")
author.send_keys("Пушкин")

author = driver.find_element_by_name("TERM_2")
author.send_keys("Капитанская дочка")

button = driver.find_element_by_name("SEARCH")
button.click()

books = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Детальная информация"]')

for book in books:
    print(book.get_attribute("href"))
                
driver.close()
```

Comment: In the PHP script - remove ALL non-essential elements such as `header.php`, the `alert` function etc etc and just leave the essential bits. Also - there is no sanity check to see if the session variables actually exist before calling them - check the PHP error log and look at the apache error log too

Comment: perhaps worth noting also are the commands [escapeshellcmd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: I've deleted non-essential part of code and arguments in execution of script, tried again but there is no result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after exchanging Chrome webdriver on Firefox webdriver